# installing php 5.4 on mac, change version?? (returns older version?)

Tags: php

Im trying to update php to 5.4, and I think ive installed it with http://php-osx.liip.ch/.
But when i do `php -v` it says that i have 5.3.15. But if i do `/usr/local/php5/bin/php -v` it says 5.4.9. Is there something i should change to get 5.4 as default?

here's a pic of Terminal: [image]

(never done this before, sorry if its a stupid question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall the old version of php and make sure that the new versions directory is in the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: You should be able to use a package manager to uninstall the old package. 
After that the easiest way would be to just create a symlink from /usr/local/php5/php to /usr/bin/php. (`ln -s /usr/local/php5/php /usr/bin/php`)

Comment: hmmmm, if I do php -v in X11 it says that I have 5.4(??) and i can even start local server and it works just fine. Why doesnt it work in Terminal? THank you again!

Comment: Hm, I can't say for sure - But it's probably PATH related (a list of directories the shells/terminals/applications look for binaries (without having to provide a full path)).

Answer (score 0):

typing this in Terminal fixed it for me: `PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`